# User experience count

Tags: mysql

I have been struggling with the following problem for a long time.

I have an experience table like this

```
id | uid | positive | negative
```

`uid` - gains the experience

`positive` - is the experience positive?

`negative` - is the experience negative?

The user table look like this

```
id | username | password
```

But how can I count the net experience for a user? How can I determine if the net experience is positive or negative with a query?

Comment: Why do you have 2 columns for the same value basically? You can just have negative numbers in a `experience` column.

Comment: Not really sure what you're trying to achieve here. If positive/ negative is a count of how many times they've chosen that particular experience rating and uid is the running total or ???

Comment: Maybe posting some sample data would hlep.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT uid, SUM(positive - negative) AS NetExp
FROM experience 
GROUP BY uid
```

This shows you the net experience per user. 
What do you mean with collect it?

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to have experience as a single column and add to it and subtract from it as necessary, rather than two columns to store one number. A query that would work in your case now though would be:

```
SELECT `uid`, (`positive`-`negative`) as exp FROM `experience`
```